# Advanced Sql query to identify missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I am currently dealing with a sql server table 'suburb' which has a suburb_id column and an adjacent_suburb_ids column. The adjacent_suburb_ids column is a comma separated string of other suburb_ids.

I have found that some of the records are not reciprocating -

e.g "SuburbA" has "SuburbB" id in adjacent_suburb_ids but "SuburbB" does not have "SuburbA" id in adjacent_suburb_ids

I need to identify all the suburbs which are not reciprocating the adjacent_suburbs, can I do this with a SQL query?

Please do not comment on the data/table structure as it is not in my control and I can't change it.

Comment: What data type is the `adjacent_suburb_id` column? Also, is this query your asking for going to be a one time script to fix things or is it meant to be a routinely ran script?

Comment: adjacent_suburb_ids column is a comma separated string. 
I would like to fix the data, but simply identifying the offending rows would be sufficient. Thank @Wesley

Comment: Do you know the column datatype? Varchar, blob, text, etc? I know you can't change the table structure but can you create a temp table?

Comment: Do you have full permissions on the database? Can you create a temp table?

Comment: Yes I have permissions. and thanks for the datatype question, it has identified that the reason some are not reciprocating was because of the 75 char limit whenever this table was created an populated.

Comment: +1 for answering a question that wasn't asked. Happy to help.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no true way to 100% fix your problem. Knowing that your data isn't correct because it was truncated due to data type length, there is nothing stopping an id from being truncated in the middle. So instead of being adjacent to id 213, the database value was truncated at 21. Your data set is corrupt and cannot truly be restored properly.

Comment: @Wesley Well I'm not sure how the data got this way. However, each records adjacent SuburbIds always ends in a ',' meaning that Id's were probably not truncated but rather just failed on insert of some of the ids. So hopefully it's not corrupted  but just incomplete. Im handing over the affected records to the BA team to sort out :) Thanks again Wesley

Comment: Even if it's not truncated. What to say you didn't lose both adjacency due to failed inserts.

Comment: Yes I see your point @Wesley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can join the table to itself using the `like`  and `not like` operators:

```
select s.suburb_id, s2.suburb_id as s2id
from suburb s 
  join suburb s2 on 
    s.suburb_id <> s2.suburb_id
    and ',' + s2.adjacent_suburb_ids + ',' like 
        '%,' + cast(s.suburb_id as varchar(10)) + ',%' 
    and ',' + s.adjacent_suburb_ids + ',' not like 
        '%,' + cast(s2.suburb_id as varchar(10)) + ',%'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc8606/1)

You need to concatenate the comma before and after to do a search within the set.  And yes, if you had the chance, you should consider normalizing the data.